# How to add labels to points of a s.class plot in package ADE4?

Tags: r, plot, label, scatter-plot

I use PCA analysis to study variability between different environments (lone).

Here is an example of the structure of my dataset :

```
station lone camp connectivite      CH4uM     CO2uM       COD    NH4     PO4    NO3 Pbiodispo
1  BRE_A_1  BRE    1       plesio  3.4923656  18.03207  9.807239 0.3390  3.1050 0.0410  67.29592
2  BRE_C_1  BRE    1       plesio  3.4923656  18.03207  8.738280 0.5200  2.7650 0.0715  71.38090
3  GAB_B_1  GAB    1         eupo  0.9720746  38.37992  2.240908 0.1380  1.2345 0.2145  50.33479
4  GAB_C_1  GAB    1         eupo  1.7596341  51.26333  9.924198 0.1070  0.9795 0.3600  85.03268
5  MAT_A_1  MAT    1         eupo  0.1718765  36.24692  4.161704 0.2145  0.0000 0.6740  35.63074
6  MAT_B_1  MAT    1         eupo  0.2096405  38.37380  3.716913 0.7445  3.5085 0.5750  60.54012
7  MAT_C_1  MAT    1         eupo  0.2595102  43.93613  3.723349 0.3420  6.1665 0.3960  73.99324

pcatot<-dudi.pca(data_totale[5:19],scannf = FALSE,center=T,scale=T, nf = 3)
```

Once I've made my PCA, I represent it using the function: s.class

```
s2tot<-s.class(pcatot$li, data_totale$lone,plabels.boxes.draw = FALSE,plabels.alpha = 1,plabels.cex = 0.2, ppoints.cex = 0.8, pellipses.lwd = 2.3, ellipseSize= 1.2,xax = 1, yax = 2, paxes.draw = TRUE,facets = data_totale$lone)
```

[image]

I would now like to add labels to the points in my PCA in order to identify the names of the points (A,B,C) in each environment and the number of the associated field campaign (1,2,3).

But I've only just managed to get the labels I wanted with a function s.label :

```
s.label(pcatot$li, data_totale$lone, plabels.boxes.draw = FALSE, xax = 1, yax = 2, paxes.draw = TRUE, label = data_totale$station,plabels.alpha = 1,plabels.cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

I would like to obtain the same label as in my s.label plot but on the ellipses of my s.class plot.

Thank you in advance for your help